# Maven executing JAR error: "no main manifest attribute"

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar

I have a made a simple maven app which should be producing a jar which I can execute to start up a vert.x instance. My issue is executing the jar file. After searching, most issues show that the `no main manifest attribute` error shows because there is no main class declared in the manifest. I am using Maven and am declaring the main class as shown below in my pom.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>firstAttempt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-unit</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Starter</Main-Class>
                                        <Main-Verticle>com.firstAttempt.Verticle</Main-Verticle>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <artifactSet />
                            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: what's <Main-Verticle> entry? I think that why it doesn't add Main-Class manifest entry

Comment: obtained from this: http://vertx.io/blog/my-first-vert-x-3-application/

Comment: can you check MANIFEST.MF file created inside the generated jar file and see whether you got Main-Class entry?